# HP Pavilion dv6-6b26sa shutdown thermal overheating

Tags: 12.10, 64-bit, hp, overheating, dv6

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my laptop. Since installing it, I can use it for about 30-45 minutes before it shuts down and on next reboot I get a warning about thermal overheating.

I've tried using the AMD/ATI Prop Drivers but that resulted in getting an error about low-graphics mode. I tried to fix this error using an Ubuntu guide to reinstall `fglrx`. This fixed the low-graphics error but didn't fix the overheating. Running `fglrxinfo` says I have no adapter.

- Why is my laptop overheating?
- If it is the graphics card, how do I fix it?

I wiped my HDD to make Ubuntu my main OS as it ran like a dream in VMware and I'd love to make this my main OS.